# How to loop through MS Access tables using Python

Tags: python, ms-access

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

oAccess = Dispatch("Access.Application")
oAccess.Visible = False
oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(my_db)
oDB = oAccess.CurrentDB

for tbl in oDB.TableDefs:
     print(table.Name)
     tbl.RefreshLink
```

I've also done:

```
for tbl in oAccess.TableDefs:
     print(table.Name)
     tbl.RefreshLink
```

Error: 'function' object has no attribute 'TableDefs'

I'm starting to understand how to manipulate Windows using win32com, but for some reason it seems like ".TableDefs" isn't recognized. Am I going about it the wrong way?

I know this can be done in VBA. I've been tasked with switching everything over to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first error, here, is that VBA knows `CurrentDb` is a method, and can't assign a method to a variable, so it invokes the method.

Python, however, has 0 problems with assigning a method to a variable, so just does so. Which means you need the parentheses to invoke the method:

```
oDB = oAccess.CurrentDb()
```

This fixes the immediate issue (same goes for `tbl.RefreshLink`, this likely should be `tbl.RefreshLink()`).

Furthermore, you never define `table`, only `tbl`, so you likely want `print(tbl.Name)`.

Comment: Thank you! I started my project using "oAccess.CurentDb()" with the parentheses. The reason I removed them is because it opens up a blank access db that I can't exit out of, even when I call 'quit'.
https://imgur.com/OWngiBe

Any idea on how stop that or why it does it?

Comment: That's the Access application opened by your Python session. It will remain open until you deallocate the COM object. So after `oAccess.Quit` you will still need `oAccess = None` (and possibly `gc.collect()` to force garbage collection). Btw, `oAccess.Visible = False` to hide it.

Comment: I did oAccess.Quit and oAccess = None and that instance of Access is still there.

When I do gc.collect() it says name 'gc' is not defined. is that not the name of it?

Comment: @Mofongo Try `import gc`. Sometimes the application remains open through open references, so try removing those as well (`oDB = None`, `tbl = None`)